# How to load a large stored pandas dataframe as fast as possible?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am working with a pandas dataframe that I need to save for later inspection. Currently I am serializing/deserializing it with the following:

```
# write
with open(self.fp, 'w') as f:
    self.df.to_json(path_or_buf=f, orient='records')

# read
self.df = pd.read_json(f.read(), orient='records')
```

However, this is quite slow! Perhaps about ten times slower than just a normal `json.loads()`. Is there a better format to save for pandas so that I can open it at a later time without having to wait a few minutes? Perhaps something like `from/to_pickle`, or what's the suggested fastest way to do this?

(Also, note that this is my local stuff/data so I'm not concerned about any security issues with any user-entered data.)

Comment: why don't you run an experiment and report findings?  You could try `to_json`, `to_pickle`, `to_csv`, `to_hdf`, and `to_feather` methods.

Comment: have you tried your own pickle suggestion?

Comment: The pandas docs have a section on [performance considerations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#performance-considerations) for various IO methods

Comment: @jsmart thanks for sharing -- yea pickle looks like it's the best, for methods that don't need special libraries installed (hdf, feature, etc.)